# Проблема с Google maps API (for development purposes only)

Tags: php, yii, google-maps-api, google-maps, карты

На сайте реализована карта с отметками ресторанов города. Реализовано с помощью google maps. Нужно добавить новые отметки, но нет доступа к google аккаунту, через который это делали. Есть ошибка for development purposes only, которая говорит о том, что нужно обновить API-ключ от google. Можно ли без доступа к google аккаунту, через который добавляли эти отметки, избавиться от ошибки и добавить новые отметки? Может быть, есть ещё какие-то варианты? Сайт написан на yii1 Ссылка на саму страницу: http://www.zm-coffee.ru/shop
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Код карты находится на сайте и он никак не связан с аккаунтом. Google-аккаунт нужен только для биллинга, так что можете создать и указать свой ключ API.

Comment: А можете подсказать, как это сделать? Где можно ознакомиться с этим подробнее?

Comment: Вот подробная инструкция https://nethouse.ru/about/instructions/kak_poluchit_apikey_dlya_kart_google

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь новым ключем по [инструкции](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY20-Q3-global-demandgen-displayonnetworkhouseads-cs-GMP_maps_contactsal_saf_v2&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_375946495640-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20SKWS%20%7E%20Maps%20%7C%20BMM%20%7C%20Mapping%20APIs-KWID_43700046387144845-kwd-297933066873-userloc_1030273&utm_term=KW_%2Bmaps%20%2Bapi-ST_%2Bmaps%20%2Bapi&gclid=Cj0KCQiA5vb-BRCRARIsAJBKc6J1njYE_qwWvYtDT-xo57YTqEKy-HUn6tFvzoj-D1vPuCf9tZ0yVZkaAv1TEALw_wcB) предоставленной от самого `google`. Заказчику скиньте эту инструкцию, чтобы создал вам ключ от его аккаунта, увидев это, он предоставит доступ :)